# What change of variables is used in this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, change-of-variable

I was following a lecture yesterday and we were computing the product of two independent identically distributed Gamma random variables, in the calculations we stumbled upon this integral:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{-z-x^2}{bx}} \,dx$$

and we said that with a change of variables this becomes a Bessel modified function of the second kind:

$$\int_1^{+ \infty} \frac{e^{-2 (t\sqrt{z})/b}}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} \, dt$$

I can't find this change of variables, what is it?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be:

$$\frac{z+x^2}{x}=2t\sqrt{z}$$

that is:

$$x^2-2 xt\sqrt{z}+z=0$$

$$x=\frac{2t\sqrt{z}\pm \sqrt{4t^2z-4z}}{2}=t\sqrt{z}\pm \sqrt{t^2z-z}$$

$$x=t\sqrt{z}+ \sqrt{t^2z-z}=\sqrt{z}(t+ \sqrt{t^2-1})$$

$$dx=\left(\sqrt{z}+ \frac{tz}{\sqrt{t^2z-z}}\right)dt=\left(\frac{z\sqrt{t^2-1}+zt}{\sqrt{t^2z-z}}\right)dt=\sqrt{z}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t^2-1}+t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\right)dt$$

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\right)dt \quad \square$$

Comment: So the extremes of integration are wrong? I think this is the only possibility

Comment: The upper $+\infty$ seems ok, for the lower bound seems that there’s a problem.

Comment: My professor just emailed me saying it is correct and I am not using the structure of the function $x \rightarrow x +z/x$ .